# Django paypal returns error : render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'

Tags: django, django-paypal

I am trying to implement the the paypal checkout button. I'm using django-paypal. I keep getting this error : render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'. I have no clue what's causing it. I am using django 2.1.

Here's my paypal process view:

```
def payment_process(request):
    template = loader.get_template("payment/process.html")
     paypal_dict = {
        "business": "henryemeka34@yahoo.com",
        "amount": "100.00",
        "item_name": "name of the item",
        "invoice": "unique-invoice-id",
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "notify_url": request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('paypal-ipn')),
        "return": request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('payment:done')),
        "cancel_return": 
request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('payment:cancelled')),
        # "custom": "premium_plan",  # Custom command to correlate to some function later (optional)
}

    # Create the instance.
    form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
    context = {"form": form}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))
```

Comment: Can you post the full error? It looks like potentially the problem is somewhere else

Comment: I just figured out the issue. It turns out I just needed to update django-paypal. The version I was using is deprecated.